# Problem with Intel 945GM graphics card

Tags: intel-graphics, 15.10

Hi recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 and I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 and I could tell my problem with graphics card for graphics acceleration is time-consuming and also that seeing a video in full screen this is cut is not smooth as it should, above had already had this problem and I remember having solved xorg.conf but eh I realized that this distribution does not come this file if you look from the recovery option so as not solve this problem.

The graphics card that has my computer is Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM / GMS, 943 / 940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
it is already old.